# Unable to install a private npm package inside GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions

I have a private npm package inside an organization that I'm using in my project. I've successfully been able to create tokens and publish the package from a different workflow, however, when trying to build the project with that package in a different repo, I'm getting an error.

What I've tried:

1. I've set up an npm access token that gives read permissions for packages in the organization. I've set this as a workflow secret called `NPM_TOKEN` in my GitHub organization.
2. I've tried setting the `scope` to my organization when running the workflow:

   ```
   jobs:
     build-dev:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - uses: actions/checkout@v3
         - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
           with:
             node-version: "18.x"
             scope: "@MYORG"
         - name: npm ci, build
           run: |
             npm ci
             npm run build-dev
           env:
             NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
   ```
3. I've tried writing the auth token from the GitHub Actions secrets to `.npmrc`.

   ```
    jobs:
     build-dev:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - uses: actions/checkout@v2
         - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
           with:
             node-version: 18.x
         - name: Authenticate with private NPM package
           run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" > .npmrc
         - name: npm ci, build
           run: |
             npm ci
             npm run build-dev
   ```

None of these things I tried worked and I get the following error every time:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@MYORG/ui-package/-/ui-package-1.0.0.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@MYORG/ui-package@https://registry.npmjs.org/@MYORG/ui-package/-/ui-package-1.0.0.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I've also read through the docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#installing-a-package) but that didn't resolve my issue either.

Comment: What is the feed url for your package? Right the url you're putting in the npmrc is for the official name registry.

Comment: @jessehouwing it's configured to use https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not adding the scope and registry during to `actions/setup-node` step. You also need to have the  `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` present in the env when installing node modules, in my case I already had it.

This is the working example:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build-dev:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          registry-url: "https://registry.npmjs.org"
          scope: "@MYORG"
      - run: npm ci
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build-dev
```